# What are the limitations of Flutter's drawVertices in a web app?

Tags: flutter, canvas

I am investigating the possibility of creating a game using Flutter.
I tested Canvas.drawVertices. It works very well and fast on desktop and mobile. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work properly in a web app. The HTML renderer has some weird clipping problems that I couldn't find a way to fix. The CanvasKit renderer works better, but only when painting solid color or an image. Color gradients and custom shaders do not seem to work.

I was expecting that using Canvas.drawVertices will operate correctly and similarly on all platforms, but it seems like it behaves substantially differently in a web app.

I am looking for advice from somebody more knowledgeable on the subject regarding:
Am I doing something wrong. Is this supposed to work differently?
Should Canvas.drawVertices be considered stable for web apps at this point?
Or is it still an experimental feature?
Is there any official resource that contains information on what is supposed to work at this point and what is being planned for the future?
Is it wise to count on its current behavior when starting a project?
Is it possible that this feature gets dropped or majorly changed in the future?